# jquery masking number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using a function to mask the number input into my textbox but i want to assign the value prior to masking it to a knockout observable. I am unsure of where in my function i can grab and store that value since when you enter a value in the textbox and tab out the values are replaced by "*" as intended only for display. So where my textbox displays ***111 my observable should have a value of 1111111.

```js
    var viewModel = function () {
        $(".textboxsemimedium").on("keydown keyup",
            function (e) {
              
                $(this).prop("value",
                    function (i, o) {
                        if (o.length < 6) {
                      
                            return o.replace(/\d/g, "*");
                        }
                    });
            });
        self.theMemberNo = ko.observable();
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <input class="textboxsemimedium" data-bind="value:theMemberNo"  data-val="true" data-val-length="Member Number be of 9 characters!" data-val-length-max="9" data-val-length-min="9" data-val-required="Member Number is required!" id="MemberNumber" maxlength="10" name="MemberNumber" title="Member Number is Required!" type="text" value="">
<span data-bind="text:theMemberNo"></span>
```

Comment: It is not solving the issue but you should use knockout event binding _data-bind="value: theMemberNo, event: {keyup: <your function>}"_ instead of using jquery. It is cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this https://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/
Then you implement it like so `$('#user-password-2').dPassword();`
It works similar to iphone password.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the theMemberNo to the input value. So that, if value changes from 1 to * the observable changes too.

I wouldn't bind the value of the input text to an observable I would just bind the event *keyup* and then, I would have an observable to keep the original value. Obviously, you will have to keep up to date this observable every time there is a keyup event.